# Silverlight control not being garbage collected because of command

Tags: silverlight, memory-leaks

My control is being kept alive because of command it is bound to.  How can I break this reference?  This is causing a major memory leak in my application.  The control is inside of a DataTemplate so I have no direct access to it.

Here is my ANTS memory profile:

[image: ANTS memory profile]

How on earth do I break this connection?

Comment: Check out this link: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/177550/418045.aspx

Comment: Great, but what the heck is `WeakEventListenerBase`.  It isn't implemented or documented anywhere. http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=WeakEventListenerBase

Comment: If you follow the link in one of the posts, you get to here: http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/02/17/weakeventsource-implementation-2/

Comment: I've seen that. I'm obviously still missing something. It doesn't talk much about `WeakEventListenerBase`. Only to say that it "is new due to the refactoring that was needed to get a non-generic declaration for the CreateWeakEventListener method return value."  What is a `WeakEventListener`?  I'm new to weak references.

Comment: You're right, I misread the source file's title. Not sure where he got WeakEventListenerBase, but he has another link with what *seems* like full source for a similar implementation: http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/02/11/simple-weak-event-listener-for-silverlight/

Comment: Turns out week listener base is just an abstract base class with a single abstract `Detach` method (no arguments).  This just gives a common non-generic base type that `CreateWeakEventListener` can return without being type specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I incorporated `WeakEventListener`, I discovered that my problem was with the control I was using to wrap up my images.  I was hooking it up to `DownloadProgress`, `ImageOpened`, and `ImageFailed` events and never unhooked them.  My thinking was that nothing else in my code was touching the `BitmapImage` objects so they would be garbage collected with the control.  This, it sees, is not the case.  The `BitmapImage` objects were referenced by a static member (and therefore a GC root) deep within Microsoft's code called "ManagedPeerTable.PeggedManagedPeersWithRefs".  It was so deep that a Google search returned only five results for it. Now I suppose there will be six.