# How to release reference to object from ManagedObjectReference?

Tags: c#, silverlight, memory-management, memory-leaks, csla

I'm investigating a memory leak issue in our Silverlight application, and found an object that is supposed to be cleaned up at the end but is still alive. 
This object contains lots of data and takes like 25MB of memory which is not released.

After doing some reference cleaning, I ended up with this

[image: Instance graph captured using Memory Profiler]

I googled around but could not find a way to clean up this reference from ManagedObjectReference.
Is it supposed to be there and how do I clean it up so the object gets garbage collected?
The application was built using Silverlight and CSLA.Net

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031962/silverlight-control-not-being-garbage-collected-because-of-command/6139515) may help.

Comment: `FieldData` is used to store property field data within each of your CSLA object instances. It _should_ be the case that when your domain object is released and GCed that the `FieldManager` is also GCed, along with the `FieldData` objects it contains. `FieldManager` is basically just a collection of `FieldData`.

If your domain object is never released though, then it wouldn't be GCed, and so neither would its `FieldManager`.

Comment: Hi @RockfordLhotka, any idea what may cause the domain object not getting collected or released?

Comment: It is most likely your Silverlight page/form that is holding a reference.In most cases the page has a link to a viewmodel, the viewmodel a link to your domain object. A common scenario is having a page navigation or menu system that keeps pages in memory, and thus the viewmodel and model.